# No logical name for any network adapter 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless, ethernet

I have no network connectivity this morning (no problems at all yesterday) on a desktop running 16.04. I cannot directly paste command outputs for obvious reasons, but I'll try to describe the problem.

`lshw -C network` displays both my wireless and ethernet cards yet no physical id and no logical name for either.

I attempted to manually add eth0 to /etc/network/interfaces as follows thinking/hoping perhaps ifup would assign it to something?!

```
auto eth0

iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

When I run

```
$ifup eth0
```

I get errors as follows;

```
"Cannot find device "eth0" Error getting hardware address for eth0"
```

How can I get a logical name assigned to my network adaptors?

Comment: Run `ip link show | grep -o eth0` to see if that named device is present

Comment: Only lo is present

Comment: Try this `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`

Comment: No clear error but lo remains the only device.

 sudo systemctl status NetworkManager shows;  nm_device_get_device_type: assertion 'NM_IS_DEVICE (self)' failed

Comment: Please check your hardware...How old is your system?

Comment: About a year. The Ethernet is integrated in the motherboard and the wifi is on it's own network card so it is unlikely to be a hardware error affecting both at once.

edit;  I am commenting from a laptop on the same network, via wifi so the network is fine

Comment: Booting from a USB also confirmed to work, it isn't a hardware problem.

Comment: Did you lose network connection after the PC woke from sleep?  This happens sometimes on my laptop (where I use WiFi only).  To resolve this I use systemctl to restart network-manager (as @George), `ip link set wlo1 down; ip link set wlo1 up` (and restore my default gateway).  In extreme cases I remove several kernel modules and insert them again.

Comment: I've managed to revert to a previous linux kernel and have life once again. Something seriously broke during a kernel update yesterday it seems. The key here was that lo is the only available device, the others didn't get assigned a logical name. Why/how that can occur was the crux of my question.

Answer (score 0):

This error is something specific to ubuntu. To be able to configure interfaces using commands ifup and ifdown or ifconfig up and ifconfig down, you need to add those interfaces to the file:

/etc/network/interfaces

Open this file using

$nano /etc/network/interfaces

You find the first line says that:

## interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

so, add the interface you want to that file, then restart the networking service, and you will be able to run the command.

1 - Open the file for edit

2 - add the line (in a new line)

auto (interface_name_without_bracets)

3 - save the file and exit

4 - $sudo service networking restart

5 - Try the commands ifup  or ifdown